# How to get Inventory for merchant fulfilled product using amazon mws api?

Tags: api, amazon-mws, inventory

I am using MWS api for fetching inventory using ListInventorySupplyAsyncSample call but it gives inventory only for amazon fulfilled product.
How to get inventory for product fulfilled by merchant?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListInventorySupply` call is part of the `Fulfillment Inventory API` which deals exclusively with FBA (Fulfillment by Amazon) stock located in one of the Amazon warehouses.

Your own (merchant fulfilled) stock in your own (non-Amazon) warehouse is probably managed best outside Amazon, but should be available to "download" form Amazon by using the `RequestReport` call with a ReportType of `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_`. I haven't tried this myself, though.

Comment: thanks hazzit....but is there any other way becoz during report call first need to download the file and then by reading that file data get fetched which require more time

Comment: @ara I don't think there is another call outside the Reporting API that does what you want - at least as of now.

Comment: @ara since you're new to StackOverflow: if you feel your question has been answered, please "accept" the answer

Comment: All _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_ does is request a tab delimited report file that you can fetch at a later time / date.  This is not sufficient and I'm lost along with ara on WHY amazon doesn't offer an equivalent for merchant fulfilled inventory.

Comment: @jtubre "This is not sufficient" for what?

Comment: @Hazzit not sufficient for real-time inventory updating.  After more research it appears such functionality would be too taxing on Amazon's servers for merchants with millions of SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

You may see through my code
use meertism's package from [GitHub](https://github.com/meertensm/amazon-mws)

```
`<?php
 $amazonSellerId         = 
 $amazonMWSAuthToken     = 
 $amazonAWSAccessKeyId   = 
 $amazonSecretKey        = 
 $amazonMarketPlaceId    = 
 $client = new MCS\MWSClient([
 'Marketplace_Id' => $amazonMarketPlaceId,
 'Seller_Id' => $amazonSellerId,
 'Access_Key_ID' => $amazonAWSAccessKeyId,
 'Secret_Access_Key' => $amazonSecretKey,
 'MWSAuthToken' => $amazonMWSAuthToken // Optional. Only use this key if you are a 
  third party user/developer
  ]);
  $reportId = $client->RequestReport('_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_');
  sleep(20); 
  $report_content = $client->GetReport($reportId);
  foreach($report_content as $i)
  {
       if($i['seller-sku'] == sku)
         { $qty=$i['quantity'];
          }
  }
  echo $qty;`
```

Comment: this answer is incomplete. please flesh it out so everyone can understand it without relying on you github link

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the Amzpecty API service to get real-time inventory of Amazon sellers given the ASIN.

Comment: Do not post one-liners. Consider elaborating your answer a bit, or move it to comments.